# Get language code of WPML

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the language code of the WPLM wordpress plugin. This is how I'm doing it without luck:

```
<?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es_En') { ?>
    <p>Spanish text</p>
<?php> ?>
```

Any idea where is the problem? I have check some tutorials and they do this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`es_En` isn't a valid language code. You'll want to just use `es`:

```
<?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
    <p>Spanish text</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (substr(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE,0,2) == 'es') { ?>
    <p>Spanish text</p>
<?php> ?>
```

Comment: That's a nice "hack"...but the real problem is that `'es_En'` isn't a valid language code.